# Android, passing Extras from activity, to fragment activity, to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, bundle

I have a main activity class with two buttons. The button pressed sends an int[] and int to a fragment activity, which is accessed by a particular fragment in that activity. I am getting nullpointer exceptions when trying to send an intent from the activity to the fragment activity, and retrieving a bundle from the fragment activity from the fragment. I know this explanation sounds confusing, here is my code:

From my main activity:

```
vessel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //System.out.println(vessel.getText().toString()+" pushed");
                int id = j;
                datasource.openRead();
                trips = datasource.tripsWithVesselId(id);
                datasource.close();
                Intent frags = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FragmentMenu.class);
                frags.putExtra("trips", trips);
                frags.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(frags);
            }
        });
```

From FragmentMenu:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frag_menu);


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        TripReportsFragment frag = new TripReportsFragment();
        frag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
    }
}
```

From my Fragment Class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        trips = getArguments().getIntArray("trips");
        vessel = getArguments().getInt("id");           
    }
    System.out.println(vessel+" vessel id from mainactivity");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trip,
            container, false);
    Button newTrip = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newTrip);
    Button pastTrips = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pastTrip);
    newTrip.setOnClickListener(this);
    pastTrips.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}
```

My vessel ID is returning 0 from the fragment class, so I know the bundle is null. I'm very unfamiliar with fragments, so any insight will be very helpful, thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have changed the code to be altered inside of the SectionPagerAdapter, it now looks like this:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TripReportsFragment frag = new TripReportsFragment();
            frag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
            return frag;
        case 1:
            return new InactivityReportFragment();
        case 2:
            return new SpeciesFragment();       
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now I am getting a new error:

01-10 14:26:04.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2538): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment TripReportsFragment{b1da3798 id=0x1020002 android:switcher:2131230762:0}: was 16908290 now 2131230762

Perspective on this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have shown, you are setting arguments only here:

```
 if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        TripReportsFragment frag = new TripReportsFragment();
        frag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
    }
```

savedInstanceState is non null only on configuration change, so initially your fragment will have no arguments set. Is your fragment initialized from layout file? - is it created in mSectionsPagerAdapter? If so maybe you are not calling setArguments there?

Comment: I'm honestly not too sure. I saw the savedInstanceState != null line from another code exerpt I saw while researching my issue. Like I said, I'm horribly unfamiliar with how fragments work. The fragments are returned in the SectionsPagerAdapter that mSectionsPagerAdapter is derived from. All that happens there is a getItem() method with a switch statement that simply returns a new fragment, so

return new TripReportsFragment();

Comment: You should call setArguments also on fragment instances created in SectionsPagerAdapter, otherwise getArguments will return you null pointer. Also I dont think you need this code inside if(savedInstanceState != null){ .... }, fragments should handle configuration changes on itself.

Comment: I assume here that TripReportsFragment  is inside your viewpager, but that might be not true.

Comment: I have edited the main post to reflect my current changes. I put the fragment setArguments where it is instantiated, now I'm getting a new error I describe in the above post and I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: remove: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit(); line from adapter

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
```

from:

```
case 0:
       TripReportsFragment frag = new TripReportsFragment();
       frag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
       return frag;
```

Become:

```
case 0:
       TripReportsFragment frag = new TripReportsFragment();
       frag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
       return frag;
```